# linux cpuset doesn't work

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, cgroups

I'm having troubles with cpusets it will be great if you could help me
I've defined two cpuset groups: "cpuset_0" which has only one task, and "cpuset_1" which is for all the other tasks in my system.
"cpuset_0" has cpus="0", cpu_exclusive="1" and only the one task assign to it.
and "cpuset_1" has cpus="1-3", cpu_exclusive="0" and all the tasks I could move as root from the root cpuset.
Both cpusets has mems="0".
The problem is that for some reason I see tasks which assigned to "cpuset_1" which are running on the exclusive cpu "cpuset_0"

For example running `ps H -eo tid,psr,cgroup,cmd`
gives me:

`2199   0  6:cpuset:/cpuset_1?5:freeze /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser`

among other processes which shouldn't be running on cpu 0.

**BTW**: I'm running kernel version 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to actually make it work without using cpuset.mems ?. It is mandatory. What does your config looks like. or you have used the mount command.

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpuset.html

try to follow the below

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Using_Control_Groups.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, both has mems="0". Thanks for the comment